# Is ' Preferred to learn practically over theoretically' a correct phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

The concept of Artificial Intelligence fascinated me and urged me to work on a project as I preferred to learn practically over theoretically. Does this sentence make any sense?

Comment: Perhaps you should say _preferred to learn practically rather than theoretically_.

Comment: @Pkjmm I would agree, "prefer ... over" and more usually "prefer ... to" are usually used with nouns, gerunds and noun phrases rather than verbs: for example "I preferred practical learning over theoretical". Even in that example "I preferred practical learning _to_ theoretical" would be more normal. I would used 'choose' with 'over' as in "I would choose practical learning over theoretical".

Comment: BoldBen: I think I agree with you on that! :)